# active record can't correctly compare a date in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie really getting stuck with the different time and date formats in ruby. 
I've figured out how to work around them until now. In this case I'm using

find_or_initialize_by_sessiondate_and_person_id() and it always creates a new record because (apparently) it doesn't recognize the date being pulled out of the database as the same as the one being provided. I'm reading data in from a CSV file and the input looks like:

```
Fri Apr 22 15:09:00 2011
```

Active record doesn't complain about this format -- it puts it in a datetime field in the database (SQLlite but I'd like the solution to work on other DB's) just fine. I tried adding a timezone to the input like this:

```
createdate = DateTime.strptime(record_split[ 4 ].chomp + " UTC","%a %b %e %T %Y %Z"
session = Session.find_or_initialize_by_sessiondate_and_person_id(createdate, person.id)
    if session.new_record?
      puts "new record for #{person.name}, #{createdate.inspect}, #{session.sessiondate.inspect}"
```

The output looks like:

```
new record for Mickey Mouse, Fri, 22 Apr 2011 15:09:00 +0000, Fri, 22 Apr 2011 15:09:00 UTC +00:00
```

This certainly looks like the same date/time to me, why is ActiveRecord creating a new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what's going on. From your example, the thing that concerns me most is the fact that "Tue Oct 5 19:43:23 2010" is being coverted to "Fri, 22 Apr 2011 15:09:00 +0000" (unless you're using different date for each example...)

To make it easier on yourself, you may be better off simply using `Time.parse` rather than `DateTime.strptime`:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > Time.parse("Tue Oct  5 19:43:23 2010")
 => Tue Oct 05 19:43:23 +1100 2010
```

The other thing to consider is that internally, Rails 3 stores all timestamps as UTC; it then displays that time in the default time-zone on-the-fly.

Finally, depending how the original timestamp field was generated (ie, Time.now vs parsing a string) you might be running into issues with precision. If `createdate` was populated using Time.now, you might find that it has been persisted with a value that is correct to the microsecond (eg: '19:43:23.34131') which, when compared to your parsed time ('19:43:23.00000') is not strictly equal.

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. I've edited to fix the examples to be consistent. I don't think it's a precision issue. The original field is just the string as shown coming in from a CSV file. It is stored in the DB, then when the file is read in again, the time doesn't match.

Comment: How is it being stored in the DB?

Comment: OK, I tried Time.parse instead of DateTime.strptime (or DateTime.parse, which I also tried.) It works!  So now I'm even more confused. Why so many Date/Datetime/Time classes in Ruby and when do you use which one? The field in the database is type DateTime, so I assumed that, when just stuffing the string in the query led to this weird result, that creating a matching DateTime object would fix it.  One difference I notice is that Time.parse inserts the local timezone in the conversion whereas DateTime.parse takes the string at face value and assumes it's UTC. Still, that does not explain this..

Comment: I'll admit, it's a bit confusing—and I still don't understand the subtle differences between them all. Thankfully, ActiveSupport seems to normalize it to an extent; Rails/ActiveSupport seems to use Time for all it's datetime fields (confusing, no?), which is what I use in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `person_id` is different?

Also this DateTimes are little differetn:

```
Fri, 22 Apr 2011 15:09:00 +0000
vs
Fri, 22 Apr 2011 15:09:00 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, person_id is the same. And yes, the datetimes print out slightly differently though they map to the same time. The question is, if active record is writing one format to the database why is it reading it out as something slightly different. But the real question is, what to do about it?

Comment: Just for giggles I tried getting rid of the DateTime.strptime call and just passed a string that looks exactly like what active record returns. I get: 'new record for Mickey Mouse, id= 1 "Fri, Apr 22 15:09:00 2011 UTC +00:00", Fri, 22 Apr 2011 15:09:00 UTC +00:00`

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to store dates in UTC, so you can have something like this in your model:

```
def sessiondate=(dt)
  write_attribute(:sessiondate, Time.parse(dt).utc)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes that works also, but I don't think it's absolutely necessary since according to @Dan the date is stored as UTC in the database anyway. What I don't get is why it's necessary to use Time.parse to create an object to store in a database field that's of type t.datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Your DateTime.new ... doesn't work on my Rails 3.0.7 but a can advice you about an other way, this is my tests in rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :028 > v = Video.new :title => "toto"
 => #<Video id: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :029 > v.save
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :030 > v
 => #<Video id: 507>
```

v.id = 507

```
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :032 > v.created_at = "Tue Oct  5 19:43:23 2010" #I use your datetime
     => "Tue Oct  5 19:43:23 2010" 
    ruby-1.9.2-p136 :033 > v.save
     => true 
    ruby-1.9.2-p136 :034 > v.created_at
     => Tue, 05 Oct 2010 19:43:23 UTC +00:00 

    ruby-1.9.2-p136 :035 > v2 = Video.find_or_initialize_by_created_at("Tue Oct  5 19:43:23 2010")
     => #<Video id: nil, ... , created_at: "2010-10-05 19:43:23", ... > 
    ruby-1.9.2-p136 :039 > v2.save
     => true 
    ruby-1.9.2-p136 :040 > v2
     => #<Video id: 508>
```

New record, v.id = 507 and v2 = 508 !

```
... > v3 = Video.
find_or_initialize_by_created_at("Tue Oct  5 19:43:23 2010".to_datetime)
```

Now with String.to_datetime method on your date string

```
   => #<Video id: 507>  # We get v !!!
 ruby-1.9.2-p136 :043 > v == v3
   => true
```

p.s: It is a I18n app it's why you don't see title attribute.

Comment: Another fix! I like it! But it doesn't work for me. But 'record_split[ 4 ].chomp.to_time' does work. Go figure. Suppose it's a difference between rails 3.0.6 and 3.0.7? Or what database you're using?

Comment: MySQL in dev, there are little diff with SQLlite. I tried for you with String.to_time on MySQL, that works too. ;)

Comment: Must be a difference in DB. Just updated to 3.0.7 and there's no change in behaviour. Thanks for checking .to_time --- nice to know that'll work when it's time to move to mysql..

Comment: Yes I'm sure that is because of to_datetime  and SQLlite (not a version problem), I advice you to use MySQL in development